# KendoUI datetime picker - Calling an on click function when previous/next month is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo-ui, datetimepicker

I'd like to trigger an on click event when the user clicks the previous/next month buttons on the Kendo UI date time picker.

[image: Kendo UI datetime picker image]

The [documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/events) tells me there isn't an event that is triggered when this happens, so I need to make an on click event.

The buttons don't have id's but do have unique classes: `k-nav-prev` for the previous month button and `k-nav-next` for the next month button.

However, when I try to put an alert for the on click event for those classes nothing happens.
Would anyone know what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to trigger an event when these buttons are clicked?

I have attached a code sample. Thanks for any help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create DateTimePicker from input HTML element
  $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    value: new Date(),
    dateInput: true
  });

  $(".k-nav-prev").click(function() {
    alert("previous month button clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="example">
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <h4>Remind me on</h4>
                <input id="datetimepicker" title="datetimepicker" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div>
            <p id="test">
              Hello world
            </p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that Kendo is already binding to clicks to those links and intercepting them. You need to use `capture` to well, capture the event before they do.

The following code will do it, but sometimes it will capture the click on the `a.k-nav-prev` element, and sometimes on the `span` with the icon inside:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if (!e.target.classList.contains("k-nav-prev") && !e.target.parentNode.classList.contains("k-nav-prev")) {
    return;
  }
  console.log("Do your thing here");
}, true);
```

Demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/etEwOYEp

More on `capture` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that Kendo intercepting them meant I had to capture the event different, you've helped a great deal :) !