# Kendo Editor not Catching Keydown Event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have a KendoEditor as below:

editor.component.html includes:

```
    <textarea>
        kendoTextArea
        name="editText"                        
        (document:click)="onUserClick()"            
        (keydown)="onKeyDown()"
        (keyup)="onKeyUp()" 
        #textAreaEditor
        value ="{{value}}">
    </textarea>
```

---

editor.component.ts includes:

```
    kendo
        .jQuery(textAreaEditor.nativeElement)
        .kendoEditor({
            resizable: {
                content: true,
                toolbar: false,
            },
            
            paste: (e: any) => {
                console.log("paste");
            },
        
            select: (e: Event)  => {
                console.log('select event fired!');           
            },
            tools: [
                'bold',
                'italic',
                'underline',
                'justifyLeft',
                'justifyCenter',
                'justifyRight',
                'justifyFull',
                
            ],
            change: (args) => {
                console.log('value Changed');
            },
        })
    .data('kendoEditor');

    const editor = kendo
        .jQuery(textAreaEditor.nativeElement)
        .data('kendoEditor');
          
    kendo
        .jQuery(editor.window).bind('keydown', onKeyDown());
    kendo
        .jQuery(editor.window).bind('keyup', onKeyUp());
```

I need to be able to trap the backspace key, but the above code is not working and does not catch the BackSpace key as part of the KeyDown event.  Can you please help?

Comment: I don't know much about Kendo Angular, but it could be that Kendo's widget is catching the event before you, like [the click event in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030733/kendoui-datetime-picker-calling-an-on-click-function-when-previous-next-month/65039347#65039347)

Comment: Thanks for your help GaloisGirl, The Kendo control that I am using here is a JQuery control, but my code is written is Angular.  I added document.addEventListener to my code the same as your code and updated it to catch the 'keydown' event instead on the 'click' event, but still didn't work.                      document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                console.log('Here in the new Keydown');
                console.log(e);
                }, true);